# How to programatically change the visual state in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visualstatemanager

I have the following code (it's just the Blend ControlTemplate of a ListBoxItem plus two new states and an event handler to ease the example):

xaml:

```
        <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Clicle"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" x:Name="list">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" MouseLeftButtonDown="LayoutRoot_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Custom">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="NotSet"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Set"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Then I the code behind I'm trying to set one of these new states:

```
    private void LayoutRoot_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(sender as FrameworkElement, "Set", true);
    }
```

Whateever I try I always get `result = false` so the state is not changed. As I'm pretty new to Visual States what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I also tried the following code to use the ListBoxItem but it also fails:

```
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as FrameworkElement);
        var a = ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(parent as FrameworkElement, "Set", false);
```

**EDIT:**

I think I found the problema while looking at the VisualStateManager. It checks that the VisualStates exist and currently the states are declared into the Border, not into the ListBoxItem (checked that calling VisualStateManager.GetVisualGroups). Any idea about why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first code looks like an xml one. Try to start from some tutorial, for example http://jesseliberty.com/2010/07/09/visual-state-manager-a-z/.

Comment: @user1929959: I don't get you. The first code is the xaml code of a Page ... nothing to do with xml

Comment: Just as comment I said that code review is one type xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used ExtendedVisualStateManager, but I don't think it is the appropriate class. Try `VisualStateManager.GoToState` and use the ListBoxItem (not the Border, which is the sender of the mouse event) as the target Control.

Comment: If I query the visualstate groups with the VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups I find the groups in the Border, not in the ListBoxItem which makes sense as they are declared inside the Border (and this is the ControlTemplate created with Blend). Anyway I tried and the result is the same, I called the VisulTreeHelper to find the parent of the Border and then called the VisualStateManager.GoToState and the same ... :S

Comment: @SoMoS Did you check that the parent is the ListBoxItem? It's possible that you've hit a broken corner case (Microsoft likes to put consistency at a low priority), since what you're doing isn't what VisualStateManager is usually used for. I would create a separate UserControl or Control, and place that in the DataTemplate. VSM will work then.